# How to create a stacked chart in VBA with multiple series?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am a VBA beginner and I am having trouble automating a chart based on the number of series that it will have. I have the following input:

[image]

[image]

I need to create a stacked chart as above and I wrote the code below, however it seems the macro is not seeing the 4th series. The other option is to set rng as Sd1:SH" & CountT + 1 and ignore rng2, however this option uses the ID values plus the first series as the values of axis X. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub GraphPs()

    Dim CountT As Integer
    Dim cht As Chart


    Range("sd1:sh200").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    CountB = 0
    CountC = 0
    CountD = 0
    CountT = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

    Set RngBegin = Range("c2:c" & CountT + 1)
    Set RngEnd = Range("d2:d" & CountT + 1)

    Mindate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(RngBeginDate)

    For i = 1 To CountT

'calculate series 2, 3 and 4. Series 1 is the values of the input in column C

        Date1 = Cells(i + 1, 3)
        Date2 = Cells(i + 1, 4)

        If Date1 = Empty And Date2 = Empty Then
            NumberD = Empty
        End If

        If Date1 <> Empty And Date2 <> Empty Then
            NumberD = Date2 - Date1
        End If

        If Date1 <> Empty And Date2 = Empty Then
            NumberD = Date - Date1
        End If

        If NumberD >= 365 Then
            Cells(i + 1, 500) = NumberD
            Cells(i + 1, 501) = 0
            Cells(i + 1, 502) = 0
            CountB = CountB + 1
        End If

        If NumberD >= 365 / 2 And NumberD < 365 Then
            Cells(i + 1, 500) = 0
            Cells(i + 1, 501) = NumberD
            Cells(i + 1, 502) = 0
            CountC = CountC + 1
        End If

        If NumberD < 365 / 2 Then
            Cells(i + 1, 500) = 0
            Cells(i + 1, 501) = 0
            Cells(i + 1, 502) = NumberD
            CountD = CountD + 1
        End If

        Cells(i + 1, 498) = Cells(i + 1, 2)
        Cells(i + 1, 499) = Cells(i + 1, 3)

    Next

'Delete old chart

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Create graph

    Set cht = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(38, 38, 400, 400).Chart
    Set Rng = Range("Se1:SH" & CountT + 1)
    Set Rng2 = Range("Sd2:sd" & CountT + 1)

    'Writes legend
    Cells(1, 498) = " "
    Cells(1, 499) = "A"
    Cells(1, 500) = "B"
    Cells(1, 501) = "C"
    Cells(1, 502) = "D"

    With cht
        .ChartType = xlBarStacked
        .HasTitle = True
        .HasLegend = True
        .SetSourceData Source:=Rng, PlotBy:=xlColumns



    With Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1)
        .Left = Range("b38").Left
        .Top = Range("b" & CountT + 5).Top
        .Width = 900
    End With``

    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = Mindate

    .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 365.25
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasMajorGridlines = True
    cht.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 500
    cht.ChartGroups(1).Overlap = 0

    .SeriesCollection(1).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With

    If CountB <> 0 Then
        .SeriesCollection(2).Select
        With Selection.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(177, 160, 199)
        End With
    End If

    If CountC <> 0 Then
        .SeriesCollection(3).Select
         With Selection.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        End With
    End If

 'here is the error in the code

     If CountD <> 0 Then
        .SeriesCollection(4).Select
        With Selection.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(196, 215, 155)
        End With
     End If

    'Format chart
    With .ChartTitle
        .Characters.Font.Bold = True
        .Characters.Font.Size = 18
        .Characters.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Text = "POR"
    End With

    With .PlotArea.Border
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With

    ' add chart area border
    With .ChartArea.Border
        .LineStyle = xlDot
        .Weight = xlThin
        .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With
    End With

Range("a37:a37").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Your indentation is horrible. If you learn to do it properly, you can clearly trace the flow of execution to see exactly what's happening. Start with doing that, and see if you can see what's wrong. If you still can't, at least you'll be able to see exactly what's happening when you're stepping through in the debugger to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Check out this cool [smart indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation)!